# Groovy script to enable/disable parameter in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

My jenkins job has got two 'String parameters' namely 'PARAM1' and 'PARAM2'

I want to enable 'PARAM2' only when 'PARAM1' has certain value in it.  I googled but could not find the closest one

How this can be accomplished in Groovy ?

Comment: define the meaning of `enabling a variable`. I'm not aware of such a term in java/groovy

Answer (score 0):

How about using a 3rd parameter that is empty by default and gets the value of parameter two in case the string matches.

```
def PARAM1 = string1
def PARAM2 = string2
def PARAM3 = 

if (PARAM1 == 'string1'){
   def PARAM3 = string2
   ...
}
```